# Как поставить проверку php (if) и проверять содержимое в корне сайта?

Tags: php

У меня есть сайт с разными языками рус, en, ua.

Как проверять то, что после домена, 
например

```
www.mysite.ru/uk/
www.mysite.ru/en_US/
www.mysite.ru/ru_RU/
```

чтобы выводить содержимое соответствующего языка?

Answer (score 0):

```
$url = 'http://www.mysite.ru/uk/';

var_dump(parse_url($url, PHP_URL_PATH)); // string(4) "/uk/"
```

[Документация](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.parse-url.php)